# In a Jekyll site using Disqus I get a Content Security Policy error

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, github-pages, content-security-policy

I built a site using Jekyll hosted on Github Pages:

[site](https://bd3r.github.io/Bad3r-blog/), 
[repo](https://github.com/bd3r/Bad3r-blog)

Jekyll [_config.yml](https://github.com/bd3r/Bad3r-blog/blob/master/_config.yml):

```
    # Comments
disqus_shortname: bad3r
```

Disqus configuration in [_layout/post.html](https://github.com/bd3r/Bad3r-blog/blob/master/_layouts/post.html) :

```html
<div class="comments-wrapper">
  <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  <script>
    /**
     *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
     *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
     */
    var disqus_config = function() {
      this.page.url = '{{ absolute_url }}{{ page.url }}'; /*Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable*/
      this.page.identifier = '{{ page.url }}'; /*Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable*/
    };
    (function() { /* dont endit below this line */
      var d = document,
        s = d.createElement('script');
      /* https://bad3r.disqus.com/embed.js */
      /* 'https://{{ site.disqus_shortname }}.disqus.com/embed.js' */
      s.src = 'https://{{ site.disqus_shortname }}.disqus.com/embed.js';
      s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
      (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
  </script>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
</div>
<!-- /.comments-wrapper -->
```

I have enabled comments in the post Jekyll front-matter:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to my new blog"
date:   2018-05-25
excerpt: "working on building my blog, here is an example post"
image: "/images/workProgress.jpg"
comments: true
---
```

link to the post where disque shows an error message [here](https://bd3r.github.io/Bad3r-blog//blog/building-a-bolg/), code on github [here](https://github.com/bd3r/Bad3r-blog/blob/master/_posts/2018-05-25-building-a-bolg.md)

if you open the console on the page you will see the error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”).
```

i didnt have a Content Security Policy when i first encountered the error 
but i tried to implement one and i added the CSP in the [_includes/head.html](https://github.com/bd3r/Bad3r-blog/blob/master/_includes/head.html) :

```html
<!-- CSP(Content Security Policy) -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Security-Policy' CONTENT="default-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.disqus.com a.disquscdn.com requirejs.org www.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' a.disquscdn.com; img-src 'self' *; media-src 'self' ; frame-src disqus.com;">
```

and the [_includes/head.html](https://github.com/bd3r/Bad3r-blog/blob/master/_includes/head.html) is included in the start of all _layouts/*.html

I have no idea why this error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may be entering an incorrect `this.page.identifier`. Here is a copy of the Disqus code on a working blog:

*_includes/disqus.html:*

```
{% if page.comments %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
            <script>
            /**
            *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
            *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
            var disqus_config = function () {
            this.page.url = "{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}";  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
            this.page.identifier = "{{ page.id }}"; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
            };
            (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
            var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
            s.src = 'https://DIRSETUP.disqus.com/embed.js'; // YOUR ACCOUNT
            s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
            (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
            })();
            </script>
            <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>             
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

The above code you'll need to copy from Disqus because it will include the URL for the site setup but in your code you have it as variable from the config. I think you may be having an issue by the reference so try changing `'{{ page.url }}'` to `"{{ page.id }}"`. In the directory `_layouts` I just pass the include of `{% include disqus.html %}` to *post.html*. In `_posts` I have a template of:

```
---
layout: post
published: false
comments: true
title: ""
excerpt: ""
date: 
categories: ['']
tags: ['', '']
---
```

If you want the comment count you could also add:

```
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//{{ disqusShort }}.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
```

before the closing `</body>` tag to *_layouts/default.html*. Then you can add `disqusShort: username` to *_config.yml*. In *_layouts/post.html* add:

```
{% if page.comments %} • <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}#disqus_thread">0 Comments</a>{% endif %}
```

When I set mine I referenced "[Adding Disqus to a Jekyll Blog](http://sgeos.github.io/jekyll/disqus/2016/02/15/adding-disqus-to-a-jekyll-blog.html)". I get no errors so hope this helps.